# Retrieve parent struct of a list_head object

Tags: c, linux, struct, linked-list, kernel

In linux kernel there's a `struct XX` which contains a `struct list_head YY`.

Now given a pointer to a `struct XX` object, I want to find all `XX` struct in the linked list. So I will go through the list_head struct, then find the corresponding parent struct.

But the second step here seems not applicable. So I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve this.

Example:

```
struct XX {
    ...
    struct list_head YY;
};
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're asking? The question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Mike added the struct XX defeinition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `container_of` macro ([LDD3 chapter 3: The open method](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)).

Comment: Or the CONTAINING_RECORD macro on Windows (you don't say what platform you're using).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to find the object containing a given list node (which you have a pointer to).  If so you want some variant of this macro:

```
  //given the address of a member, find the address of the object containing the member.
  #define GetObjectFromMember(ObjectType,MemberName,MemberPointer) \
             ((ObjectType *)(((char *)MemberPointer) - ((char *)(&(((ObjectType *)0)->MemberName)))))
```

Given a struct Foo, and a member m_bar, a pointer, p, to an instance's m_bar:

```
Foo *foo = GetObjectFromMember(Foo,m_bar,p);
ASSERT( &foo->m_bar == p );
```

I use this macro in a large number of callbacks where I'm handed a pointer to the callback object (like a timer) and need to find the surrounding object pointer.  Since the linux kernel uses intrusive lists I feel certain it already has this macro somewhere, but I've never really looked for it.

Comment: Technically the macro is a bit tricksy - it depends on specific undefined behaviour behaving in a specific way. Ideally you should use the macro provided by the platform vendor, for example container_of on Linux or CONTAINING_RECORD on the Windows DDK. These will be guaranteed to work with the compiler that you're working with.

Comment: I've been using this exact macro cross platform for more than 15 years, so I'm pretty sure it's stable.  This macro does have issues in C++ due to virtual inheritance.  That is covered by the template version this macro, but that wasn't covered by this question.

Comment: It is still undefined behaviour according to the C and C++ languages though. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use it, but it is something you need to be aware of. Which was my point.